# Image related issue when creating button dynamically

Tags: android, image, button

In my sample app, I try to create `Button` dynamically using the below code. Everything works fine, but once I set the background image to the button, what I notice is that the image becomes oval in shape. But in actual the image are circle in shape. Why this happens, is anything to do in my code? Help me to solve this.

**main.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/liVLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Jave code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private Button[][]          m_pBtnDay; 
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        m_pBtnDay = new Button[6][7];
        
        initDay();
    }
    
    public boolean initDay()
    {
        LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
        LinearLayout rowLayout = null;
        
        LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {
            rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
            
            layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout, param);
            
            for(int j=0; j<7; j++)
            {
                m_pBtnDay[i][j] = new Button(this);             
                m_pBtnDay[i][j].setTextSize(15);    
                m_pBtnDay[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.theme1_cal_button_selected);
                rowLayout.addView(m_pBtnDay[i][j], param);                                                          
            }                           
        }                       
        
        return true;
    }       
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your problem is to use `Bitmap` in drawable directory like following.

Create `an xml bitamp` file, name it `button_background.xml` in drawable directory and put following short of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```

Replace `ic_launcher` image with your one. Then instead of using your background image, use following code.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="your Text" />
```

Bingo.. This will not stretch your image.

Comment: But inside that Button i have set a text also..actually i am creating a calculator type app..so if i use imageView how can i set text on it

Comment: But how can i set text on ImageButton...Because there are no function called settext on imageButton. Similarly how can i retrive the text that is set on imageButton like getText method

Comment: @AndroidCoder, I am very sorry for my misunderstanding. Its true that `ImageButton` does not provide text property. :(

Comment: @AndroidCoder, good news for you. Solved your problem. Just check my edited answer. :)

Comment: Ok...i will try this out..but my button is created in code not in xml file..will this work in my code

Comment: @AndroidCoder, Of course. Use this background file instead of your image drawable file or image. :)

Comment: yep its work like a charm..but one minor issue is there...the text inside the button not align in center...although i used button.setGravity(Gravity.Center);

Comment: @AndroidCoder, I think then you should set some padding to your button. Like pad left and top side to adjust them.. :P